Show Hide Assets based on Taxonomy options
We have a requirement of showing certain assets to certain user groups based on taxonomy values added to these assets in the assets listing page. What could be the best way to achieve this?
To elaborate the requirement, say we have 5k assets out of which 500 are restricted and only users from a certain user group should see and edit them in the assets listing page and rest everyone will see 4.5k assets in the listing page. This requirement will be expanded upon in future so we might be having such restrictions for multiple taxonomy options. Currently most of the assets are not having the taxonomy value added and CH doesn't give us the option to explicitly deny access on any value.
I believe we can achieve this by applying security permissions but not sure how to write the same.

You can tag taxonomy A to the 500 assets and taxonomy B to the other remaining 4500 assets(default assets).
Thereafter create two user groups one with taxonomy A access and other with taxonomy B access. Then using policy combination feature we can grant access to the users whom require access on both the taxonomies or either of the taxonomies.
Policy can be configured inside the rules section on the user group polices while creating a user group as below:

Provide Access to Portal.Pages for Asset, Asset Details and Mass Edit page.



Provide access to the taxonomy values through the taxonomy relation.In the below example, access is provided to those assets which are in approved state and contains the taxonomy 'Brochure' in the AssetType relation.


Note: Using a policy to grant permissions based on a specific taxonomy value also affects entities that have no value for that taxonomy. This implies when the user has permission to the assets containing taxonomy value as brochure, then user will also have access to assets where the taxonomy value is empty.
Hope this helps!!!

We were able to achieve this with User group policies.
We have a custom Taxonomy with a relation to M.Asset as Parent.
We set the rule for Assets and add a condition where our parent taxonomy is that value.
In order to do this you will probably also need a Taxonomy value of "unrestricted" or something like that. To be able to set all other assets to this value. Then you can grant access to M.Asset where Taxonomy: "unrestricted"
This will give you 2 user groups that you can assign to different users. The users that need to see all assets will have both user groups assigned.
Hope this helps you in achieving your goal.

I can confirm that we encountered a similar requirement from one of our clients, and we tried to address it with our best possible solution.
We established separate pages for different user groups. For instance, users in UserGroup A only have access to Page A, which contains 500 assets tagged with taxonomy A. Similarly, users in UserGroup B only have access to Page B, which contains approximately 4500 assets tagged with taxonomy B.
Firstly, we created a custom Taxonomy with a relation to M.Asset as the Parent, named Visibility, with ManyToMany Cardinality.


We opted for ManyToMany since assets can be tagged with more than one
taxonomy value.

We added values such as A and B, ensuring future scalability to accommodate additional restrictions based on more user groups.

While Content Hub doesn't permit changing the Cardinality of the
taxonomy once created, it can be achieved with some steps, which I've
outlined in my blog.
https://logicalmindscom.wordpress.com/2023/10/15/tip-how-to-modify-the-cardinality-of-a-taxonomy-relation/

Next, we created separate pages for assets corresponding to each taxonomy, such as Page A for assets tagged with taxonomy A and Page B for assets tagged with taxonomy B. On these pages, we integrated an out-of-the-box search component and configured filters in the filter section to display only assets tagged with the particular taxonomy.


Once both pages were created, we established two user groups, A and B, and assigned policies accordingly. For example, User Group A can only access Page A, while User Group B can only access Page B.

This approach effectively segregates assets based on tagging and offers a future-proof solution in case there's a need to show another set of assets to an additional user group.

Here are the steps to be followed for achieving this
For this say, we will define a Taxonomy with One to Many Cardinality with two values X and Y
We will tag the 45000 Assets with Taxonomy X and in the user group A we will give access to Assets that are tagged with Taxonomy X
We will tag the remaining 500 Assets with Y and give access to User Group B with Assets tagged with Both X and Y. So the User group will have access to all 5000 Assets
